# How to ignore a return value in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to ignore a function's return value in VBA?

What I have to do in the moment:

```
Dim returnValue As Long 'This line is mandatory since I use Opition Explicit
returnValue = MsgBox("...")
```

What I would like to do

```
MsgBox("...")
```

In C++ I would solve it this way:

```
(void) MsgBox("...")
```

(How) can I solve this in Excel-VBA?

Comment: In VBA ( ) are needed only if you return a value

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't want the return value of a Function or Method, make a call without the brackets:

```
Msgbox "Test"
```

Answer (score 7):

Or use `Call`:

```
Call Msgbox("...")
```

Comment: @Ergodicity Absolutely no need to apologise! They both work. :)

Answer (score 5):

Two options:

1. Drop the parentheses: `MsgBox "Test"`
2. Use the `Call` keyword: `Call MsgBox("Test")`

In your case these will be *exactly* equivalent, but in general, using `Call` can result in slightly different behaviour due to the way that it deals with any function parameters marked as `ByRef`.

Comment: Where in that article does it say anything about `Call` treating function parameters differently?

Comment: That is nothing to do with `Call` (which isn't even used in that line). It's the parentheses.

Comment: I'll build an example if I get time this afternoon.

Comment: See my earlier comment (before you deleted yours).